# Remove Substring from NSstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I see so many solution , but none of them was matching my problem .
As i am new to iOS development .

I have a String

```
abc/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/Root Folder/Level 1/Level 2/Level 1-1/Level 1/')/folders.
```

I want to remove Remove Substring after last "/"
 for example my new string should look like this.

```
abc/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/Root Folder/Level 1/Level 2/Level 1-1/Level 1/)
```

Can someone suggest me the best way to achieve this , thanks ,

Comment: You should really be using `NSURL` for file path manipulations (since iOS 4).  See NSURL documentation for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSString has a method 'stringByDeletingLastPathComponent' which does exactly what you want.
You can use it as follows:

```
NSString* origFolder = @"abc/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/Root Folder/Level 1/Level 2/Level 1-1/Level 1/')/folders";
NSString* folder = [origFolder stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSLog(folder);
```

This will log

```
abc/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/Root Folder/Level 1/Level 2/Level 1-1/Level 1/')
```

to the console.